# How do you keep track of picture/audio edits for sync?

Tags: knowledge

If you get a rough cut of a movie, and then work on it, then you get another cut, how do you keep track of the work you are doing and keep it in sync?

Answer (score 1):

EDLs, Markers and reference soundtrack (if available) are your friends in any kind of multi-edit projects. Once you know the changes, you can group tracks and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If there have have been many edits and you're pressed for time, a conforming program like Virtual Kathy would help. There's a 48hr trial version and that should be enough to get you through it. You will still need the EDL though.

Answer (score 0):

You want to ask for an EDL

In case you havent seen one before, its a readout of the timecode/frame information of the current cut - then next to current is the new revised cuts timecode/frame information. This is also accompanied by a + or - frames to tell you if they added or subtracted frames onto or from that current point. This method can vary depending upon system or picture editor working on the film.

If they cant provide an EDL, ask for a list of where they made cuts and how many frames were added/subtracted. If its a do it yourself kinda film where people might not know how to print an EDL etc, asking this way makes more sense and still gets you the info you need to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Right, thats what I thought.  EDL.